# I need to select month and year in Monthpicker but in choose month shows data and year

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a month picker in my Windows Xaml code.

This is my code

When i click this monthpicker it shows to choose the month, in that screen Date with month and year is coming.. But i need only month and year in the choosen window.

I'm newer to Windows app development. How can i acheive this [Image Attached] ?[image]

Comment: What do you use in your code? DatePicker / RadDatePicker?

Comment: Are you sure is that the date or the number of the month? Post some code

Comment: <monthpicker:mpicker x:Name="month_picker" ValueChanged="month_picker_ValueChanged"  ValueStringFormat="{}{0:MMM-yyyy}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" >

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to go for Month Picker and make yourself tough. You can simply use DatePicker tool and get the value of Month and Year alone. Just follow below code and don't worry about date.

```
<StackPanel>
    <toolkit:DatePicker Name="datePicker"/>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding StringFormat=MM-yyyy}" FontSize="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In your backend,

```
textBlock.DataContext = datePicker.Value.Value;
```